# how to compare one thing to lots of other things in python?

Tags: python, random

I'm trying to make a program to randomly create a team schedule for a scramble golf tourney (72 players divided into 4 sets, 18 teams, [each team containing one player from set A, one player from set B, one player from set C, and one player from set D] changing each week for 18 weeks, with no player playing with any player they've already played with)

Unfortunately, I have no idea what I'm doing.

I was thinking I could use random.randint to pick out the teams, then compare the teams with the previous teams, discarding and re-picking if either A: a player is already in a team for this week, or B: a player has played with one of his team members in previous weeks

I have no idea how to do this though.

Comment: And so you want create schedule where each must playing to each?

Comment: This is like a pairwise combinations problem with an additional constraint that no set can contain any of the same pairs. Since the minimal spanning set is 324 instances long, this can definitely be done.

Comment: Let me refer you to an algorithm I was working on a while ago. It's by no means complete, but should work perfectly for your situation. Here is the link: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14120/pairwise-combinations-generator